# Dynamically update value

Tags: sql, sql-server, window-functions

I have this table and I have to sort the rest after subtraction of numbers from the started numbers 350 and break if the value is equal to 0 at the end

| ID | Numbers |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 |
| 2 | 20 |
| 3 | 40 |
| 4 | 8 |

the expected result
should look

| ID | Numbers | Result |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 | 340 |
| 2 | 20 | 320 |
| 3 | 40 | 280 |
| 4 | 8 | 272 |

I am stuck on my code without knowing how to get the rest like in the table

```
with cte as (
    select id, (SELECT sum(numbers) from TABLE t2 where t2.id <= t1.id) sumT
    from TABLE T1
  )
select sumT , ( 350 - sumT) from cte where sumT <= 350
```

Comment: Some expected results, for your sample data, will help us help you.

Comment: I guess the sample data IS already the result? To avoid such issues, always both sample input AND outcome should be provided when asking SQL questions.

Comment: What is "break if the value is equal to 0 at the end" supposed to mean exactly?

Comment: Sorry if my explanation are not complete,
 If (numbers - 350) = 0, the query stop

Comment: You aren't explaining the problem here, @iceman225 . Again, some expected results will help us help you here.

Comment: What if the number does not get down to zero exactly, but say from 10 to -20?

Comment: I update my question with an exemple more clear,
Hi @Thorsten, if (numbers - 350 ) <= 0 the query stop to

Comment: Your request would benefit from you adding rows to your sample data that make the value go below zero. Don't show the most simple case, but an edge case so we get the complete picture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get the cumulative sum with `SUM OVER`. Then just show all rows where the rest is at least zero.

```
select id, numbers, 350 - so_far as rest
from
(
  select id, numbers, sum(numbers) over (order by id) as so_far
  from mytable t
) sums
where 350 - so_far >= 0
order by id;
```

If it can happen that you don't get down to zero exactly, but say -10 instead and you still want to show that last line, then show all rows where the row before had a rest greater than zero:

```
select id, numbers, 350 - so_far as rest
from
(
  select id, numbers, sum(numbers) over (order by id) as so_far
  from mytable t
) sums
where 350 - (so_far - numbers) > 0
order by id;
```

And if you don't want to show the -10, but a rest of 0 then, make this:

```
select id, numbers, case when so_far > 350 then 0 else 350 - so_far end as rest
```

As of SQL Server 16, you can also use `GREATEST`:

```
select id, numbers, greatest(350 - so_far, 0) as rest
```

Comment: Great, thanks Thorsten, this help me a lot with the little plus of information you bring me thanks

Answer (score 1):

You may use a running sum function that finds the cumulative sum of numbers over the increasing value of ID as the following:

```
SELECT ID, Numbers, Rest
FROM 
(
  SELECT ID, Numbers,
       350 - SUM(Numbers) OVER (ORDER BY ID) AS Rest
  FROM table_name
) T
WHERE Rest>=0
```

See a [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/qwHZISIn).

Comment: Great, thank Ahmed you help me a lot  !